# PHP Class function declaration issue

Tags: php, object

i have an issue with function redeclaration problem. So, i am trying to call multiple times this example.

```
class myClass {

    function abc() {

        function internal() {

        return "i am internal"; 
        }

    return internal();
    }

}


$myClass = new myClass();

echo $myClass->abc();
echo $myClass->abc(); // HERE IS THE PROBLEM when i call same function second time
```

PHP showing Fatal error: Cannot redeclare internal() (previously declared).

Does anyone have an idea how can i solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't define functions within other functions, there's no need for that.

Comment: Don't nest function definitions - there's no need to do it, it causes problems like this, and is a bad code smell

Comment: If you need `internal` to have access to variables local to `abc` then use Rocket's solution. Otherwise you should do something like what Lawrence suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare a function using `function <name>()`, you are *not* declaring it in the scope you think you are.  That function is being declared in the <strike>class</strike> global scope, not the function/class scope.

See the PHP Docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php#example-149

So, when you call `abc`, you are re-declaring the global function, `internal`.

If you want to do what you are doing, you can use [closures](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) instead (NOTE: This only works in PHP 5.3+).  This has the benefit of being able to read local variables from within `abc` (if you use the `use` keyword).

```
class myClass {

    function abc() {
        $internal = function() {
            return "i am internal"; 
        };

        return $internal();
    }
}
```

You can also declare `internal` as a private function of the class, especially if it's not going to change.  Why keep re-making a function?

```
class myClass {

    private function internal(){
        return "i am internal"; 
    }

    function abc() {
        return $this->internal();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You cant redeclare the function period so try something like this:

```
<?php 
class myClass {

    function abc() {
        return $this->internal();
    }

    private function internal() {
        return "i am internal";
    }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the function exists prior to defining it:

```
class myClass {
    function abc() {
        if ( ! function_exists('internal')) {
            function internal() {
                return "i am internal"; 
            }
        }

        return internal();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

```
if (!function_exists('internal')) { function internal ... }
```

However, you have to be aware that in this case, the function internal will be available *outside* the class scope as well. Lawrence's solution is a better approach.